# NestedScrollView and WebView height issue

Tags: android, android-design-library, androiddesignsupport

I use new `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView` and I faced with issue.

Here is my layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7">

             <!-- some views inside -->

        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

I need to load html inside textView, so I make:

`content.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlString));`

And it looks strange. My textview placed at the bottom of screen.
[image: initial state]

After I swipe on the text it starts to look normal.
[image: after swipe]

And I think textview is not only view with these issue.
I tried use webview, but it even does not show content (I think due to incorrect height computation).
So I need webview or textview to correct work with `NestedScrollView`.

P.S. If I set textview height in `dp` then text looks correctly, but I need `wrap_content` for height.

## Updated 08.07.15

Finally I need to use `WebView`. Alex Facciorusso answer partly works, but I faced with another issue. When `WebView` content has some specific height then I can see part of the content, but I can't scroll down. 
Example:
[image]

Comment: Can you try webview for displaying a HTML ..??????

Comment: @Moinkhan yeap, but webview has another issue: it even does not appear . And I have very light html, so `TextView` shows it correct.

Comment: try LinearLayout height as match_parent...

Comment: @Moinkhan I tried many configuration: `LinearLayout` set to `match_parent`, `RelativeLayout` with `match_parent` and `wrap_content`, place `TextView` directly in `NestedScrollView`. I think it is a `NestedScrollView` issue, but I can not realize what is wrong.

Comment: just do this last try ...put {app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"} to LinearLayout instead of NestedScrollView

Comment: @Moinkhan content stops to scroll at all.

Comment: Resolved this issue in support library version 2.2.1: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175234

Comment: It works for me,
 add This line to NestedScrollview in XML File.

     android:fillViewport="true"

then
    set webview height wrap_content.

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As  Mayur Raiyani said: this issue is resolved in support library version 22.2.1: [code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175234](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175234). Thanks all for answers.

Comment: I'm facing similar issues, @IIyaEremin and it doesn't seem to be fixed. The webview doesn't respect match_parents for height. Are you sure the issue is fixeD?

Comment: @onusopus IMHO design library still is very buggy and you need to use some 3rd party library.

Comment: did u face this also ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33688701/webview-height-grows-indefinitely-inside-a-nestedscrollview

Comment: Wow thanks. The question is, is there an angel descended from the sky, sent by DIVINE GODS and whispered to your ears that there is such as version 22.2.1? I reckon there is a list, I am struggling to find listings of support library versions...

Comment: @NeonWarge use the Android SDK manager to check for newer versions, and the support library changelog for an overview of what's changed http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html

Comment: @LorneLaliberte No I need the listing, I need the entire list of versions.

Comment: @NeonWarge that link contains the entire list. Each version can be expanded for more details.

Comment: @LorneLaliberte Oh Im sorry, yes of course it is! Thanks! Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 5):

Read a lot of posts, and custom implementation of WebView as well, but I was keen about experimenting with attributes and found out what works for me, which is this:

For `NestedScrollView` use attribute

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

and for the underlying `WebView` make sure you are using height as wrap

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</WebView>
```

so as a pseudo code you have

```
<NestedScrollView> // height=  match_parent

 <Parent_layout>//could be Realtive/Linear with height= match_parent
   <Some_View></Some_View>
   <Some_View></Some_View>

   <WebView></WebView> // height=  wrap_content
 </Parent_layout>

</NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: this solved the endless scroll of webview when its placed in the nestedscrollview! good one!

Comment: Oh Nice @ArunJose this worked for you! This issue keeps reminding me the solution once every year haa haa.

Answer (score 3):

A simple workaround will be to add an empty View with 500dp height below your TextView inside of your LinearLayout. That View shall push up your TextView to the right position.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- Your scrolling content -->

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/random_text" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found a workaround:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:minHeight="300dp">

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/webview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </FrameLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="256dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I added a minHeight of 500dp to NestedScrollView, and now the WebView is fitting all the height of the layout, and the collapsing toolbar is working.

**UPDATED**: wrapped WebView with FrameLayout and added minHeight to it.

Comment: Yeap, It work, but with some webview content height I see part of the content, but I can't scroll down. I tried to change minHeight to 1000dp, but nothing changed.

Comment: Updated answer: maybe it's a little better

Comment: Sorry for late. I tried to wrap `WebView` into `FrameLayout`. The result is same. You can try it for your self. Here is my xml and data for webView: https://gist.github.com/IlyaEremin/e28d51cd1341607a1e69

Comment: I like to mention wrapping the `WebView` in `FrameLayout` with the `minHeight` helped me solve an issue related to not being able to scroll the `WebView` if touching the webview's content to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

wrapped WebView with FrameLayout and added View(android:layout_height="800dp") as WebView'minHeight to it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug, update you sdk, replace "compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'" with "compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'" in build.gradle.
That's work for me.

Comment: Hi dhn! Do you know if there is an issue no associated with this? THank you!

Comment: sorry, that's all I know.

Answer (score -3):

adding `android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"` in NestedScrollView will solve your issue

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="24dp" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```