# Adding pull to refresh on webview for refreshing

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview, pull-to-refresh

I will add pull to refresh on my webview so it refresh my webview. i have seen all questions on this page but i can't find the good way to add pull to refresh...

Mainactivity.java

```
package com.vvhvb.hesselfeenstra.vvheerenveenseboys;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String url ="http://heerenveenseboys.nl/";
        WebView view=(WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        view.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        view.loadUrl(url);

    }

}
```

content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.vvhvb.hesselfeenstra.vvheerenveenseboys.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I hope anyone can help me and solve this problem for me.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You could wrap webview in Swipe refesh layout like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.vvhvb.hesselfeenstra.vvheerenveenseboys.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In java

```
package com.vvhvb.hesselfeenstra.vvheerenveenseboys;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
WebView view;
SwipeRefreshLayout mySwipeRefreshLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mySwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer);
    String url ="http://heerenveenseboys.nl/";
    view=(WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    view.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    view.loadUrl(url);

    mySwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(
    new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        view.reload();
    }
    }
    );

}

}
```

Comment: And when i paste webview.reload() it gives me an error on that line.

Comment: You have define webview in onCreate()
`Webview webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.web_view)`
and then call `webview.loadUrl("your url")` inside onCreate to initially load the wbeview.
Then call `webview.reload()` inside listener.

Comment: Can you elaborate the problem?

Comment: I have 2 errors by "mySwipeRefreshLayout" it cant resolve the symbol and LOG_TAG give's me an error it cant resolve the symbol and if i paste webview.reload() there comes an error at that line.. Mayby i can update my question? "

Comment: I have no errors but i miss the </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout> where do i place that on the content_main? If i place that behind the <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout i cant pull to refresh.

Comment: put it below
`</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView> `
Check updated answer

Comment: It works! Thank you very much! Only the problem now is the circle is staying on my screen as in this picture: http://i-cdn.phonearena.com/images/articles/162782-thumb/chrome.png

Comment: Hmm..try `mySwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);` inside `onRefresh` after reload() function.

Comment: @jitinsharma, why need NestedScrollView?

Comment: You can use scrollview too.

Comment: It wokrs Thank youuu !  But you should do 
onPageFinished {
swRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
}

Comment: This does not work for me at all, it shows plain white blank screen. because nestedscrollview is behaving rude

Comment: it works good. but i'm having a problem. my webview contains a list and my webwiew scrolls. using this, when i swipe, it just reloads rather than scrolling down in the webview. Is there anything i can do for this ?

Answer (score 21):

I think the best solution is to use `SwipeRefreshLayout` but without `NestedScrollView` inside it as [jitinsharma](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37775633/3774071) described,  beacause this possible problem :  [webview height grows indefinitely inside a nestedScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33688701/webview-height-grows-indefinitely-inside-a-nestedscrollview.).But there is another solution for scrolling problem as described by [vizZ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27916575/3774071),to implement `ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener`.So working solution shold be something like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/nonVideoLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/main_web_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1" />

        </RelativeLayout>


    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Activity parameters:

```
private WebView mWebView;
private SwipeRefreshLayout mySwipeRefreshLayout;
private ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener mOnScrollChangedListener;
```

on Activity `onCreate`:

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.main_web_view);
mySwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer);

        mySwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(
                new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onRefresh() {
                        mWebView.reload();
                    }
                }
        );
```

and implements of activity:`implements AdvancedWebView.Listener`

on Activity `onStop` :

```
mySwipeRefreshLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnScrollChangedListener(mOnScrollChangedListener);
```

and Activity `onStart`:

```
 mySwipeRefreshLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(mOnScrollChangedListener =
                new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onScrollChanged() {
                        if (mWebView.getScrollY() == 0)
                            mySwipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(true);
                        else
                            mySwipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(false);

                    }
                });
```

Comment: Yes, only this solution give smooth loading, android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView is wrap webview on load and loading is not pretty.

Comment: implements AdvancedWebView.Listener : couldnt get this.

Answer (score 2):

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
<WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

For Kotllin:

MainActivity.kt

```
var mySwipeRefreshLayout: SwipeRefreshLayout? = null
var myWebView: WebView? = null
mySwipeRefreshLayout = findViewById<SwipeRefreshLayout>(R.id.swipeContainer)

    mySwipeRefreshLayout?.setOnRefreshListener {
        Log.i("on refresh", "onRefresh called from SwipeRefreshLayout")

        // This method performs the actual data-refresh operation.
        // The method calls setRefreshing(false) when it's finished.
        myWebView?.reload();
    }
myWebView!!.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
        override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, url: String?): Boolean {
            view?.loadUrl("http://www.google.com")
            return false;
        }

        override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
            mySwipeRefreshLayout?.isRefreshing = false
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work perfectly! In your layout file, wrap the webview in a SwipeRefreshLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/webView"
       />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In your Java file, declare     `SwipeRefreshLayout mySwipeRefreshLayout;`
 outside the class.
Then, add this to the `onCreate()` method

```
    mySwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer);

        mySwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(
                        new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onRefresh() {
                                    mWebview.reload();
        mWebview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
// This is important as it forces webview to load from the instead of reloading from cache

        mWebview .loadUrl(getString(R.string.app_link));

                            }
                        }
                );
```

Comment: You don't need to add this line because its set to `LOAD_DEFAULT` mode by default
 `mWebview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);`

Answer (score 0):

Try This if you want to just pull to refresh

```
    ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.CategorySelect_lLayout_noID);
ll.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            Toast.makeText(CategorySelect.this, "action DOWN called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        } 

        return false;
    }
});
    return true;
}
```

Or if you want an icon or something like chrome

https://github.com/liaohuqiu/android-Ultra-Pull-To-Refresh

Comment: can i refresh my webview with that?

Comment: Ya you can again put loadURL(<YOUR URL>) again with some query after MotionEvent.ACTION _DOWN and if you want some more types of motion refer https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html

Comment: @Hessel Find a function to get all as your linear layout

Comment: I have RelativeLayout

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/training/swipe/add-swipe-interface.html

You can use the Swipe-to-Refresh Layout, it is easy to use and takes care of the refresh animation for you.

You can add an OnRefreshListener to refresh your webview

Answer (score 0):

During my research, I found out that there are three easy ways that you can implement pull to refresh in your Android application:

- You can use a third-party library / SDKs
  **OR**
- You can use your custom implementation (like with code snippets mentioned here). This option is more complicated but provides greater flexibility for customization
  **OR**
- In Android WebViewGold, within Config.java, just turn ENABLE__PULL_REFRESH to true

Happy scrolling!

Answer (score 0):

**Here is my part of the code that was useful for me. It handles two issues:**

1. When user has scrolled within the webview and than user again tries to scroll up than the screen was getting refreshed. However, adding the code within onStart() and onStop() handles this where it checks if user has scrolled within the webview than it disables the refresh part.
2. Calling onPageFinished() using the WebViewClient() disables the refresh icon else it goes under forever refresh loop.

   ```
   webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
   mySwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer);

   webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
   webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
   webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(true);
   webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
       @Override
       public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
           mySwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
       }
   });
   webView.loadUrl("https://www.enter your url here");

   mySwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(
           new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
               @Override
               public void onRefresh() {
                   webView.reload();
               }
           });


         }

     @Override
        protected void onStart() {
         super.onStart();

      mySwipeRefreshLayout.getViewTreeObserver()
         .addOnScrollChangedListener(mOnScrollChangedListener =
           new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
               @Override
               public void onScrollChanged() {
                   if (webView.getScrollY() == 0)
                       mySwipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(true);
                   else
                       mySwipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(false);

               }
           });
            }


       @Override
        protected void onStop() {
          super.onStop();
             mySwipeRefreshLayout.getViewTreeObserver()
       .removeOnScrollChangedListener(mOnScrollChangedListener);
         }
   ```