# SwipeRefreshLayout is not intercepting the MotionEvent of the NestedScrollingChild

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout, android-nestedscrollview, android-touch-event

I am using a [`NestedScrollWebView`](https://gist.github.com/alexmiragall/0c4c7163f7a17938518ce9794c4a5236) (heavily influenced by the [`NestedScrollView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html)), which solves many of the [known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33688701/webview-height-grows-indefinitely-inside-a-nestedscrollview) [issues](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37077954#hc10) associated with using a `WebView` in a `CoordinatorLayout`.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways|scroll|snap">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:titleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:visibility="gone"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"/>

        </FrameLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <com.example.app.widget.NestedScrollWebView
            android:id="@+id/webView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The `NestedScrollWebView` works great with the `AppBarLayout` and the `enterAlways|scroll|snap` scroll flags, but not so well with the `SwipeRefreshLayout`.

---

I removed the following line from the `NestedScrollWebView`:

```
setOverScrollMode(WebView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
```

Which makes sure the view does not display over scroll indicators. I *want* over scroll indicators to appear, but the following circumstances should not occur even with over scroll enabled.

---

From what I understand the `SwipeRefreshLayout` should intercept any touch event that causes the refresh indicator to be dragged (based on its implementation of `onInterceptTouchEvent()`). `SwipeRefreshLayout` also denies any `requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent()` to any child that has nested scrolling enabled; which is true for the `NestedScrollWebView`. Therefore, these events should be handled in the [following manner](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html):

> If you return true from `onInterceptTouchEvent()`, the child view that
>   was previously handling touch events receives an `ACTION_CANCEL`, and
>   the events from that point forward are sent to the parent's
>   `onTouchEvent()` method for the usual handling.

Instead, the behavior I see is that the `SwipeRefreshLayout` does spy on the touch events of the `NestedScrollWebView` but it never actually *intercepts* them. As evidenced by the fact that the `NestedScrollWebView` never receives an `ACTION_CANCEL` touch event, and it continues to receive subsequent events even though the `SwipeRefreshLayout` indicator is being dragged down.

This is demonstrated in the following screenshot; which shows the indicator of the `SwipeRefreshLayout` as well as the over scroll indicator of the `WebView` being displayed at the same time.

[image: overscroll and refresh indicator shown in tandem]

I cannot figure out why this would be the case. As I mentioned previously, the `SwipeRefreshLayout` should  work well with any view that has nested scrolling enabled, but for some reason it does not work in this case. What could be the issue?

---

#### Update

I think it has something to do with the way the `NestedScrollWebView` handles `dispatchNestedPre...` methods and the fact that it always passes the entire `MotionEvent` to the `super.onTouchEvent()` method. According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/NestedScrollingChild.html#dispatchNestedPreScroll(int,%20int,%20int[],%20int[])):

> Nested pre-scroll events are to nested scroll events what touch
>   intercept is to touch. `dispatchNestedPreScroll` offers an opportunity
>   for the parent view in a nested scrolling operation to consume some or
>   all of the scroll operation before the child view consumes it.

Now I have to figure out how to rework the `NestedScrollWebView` to handle these methods properly.

Comment: Probably the most simplest solution is replace `NestedScrollWebView` with `NestedScrollView` which wraps `WebView`.

Comment: @StasLelyuk I should have mentioned; I moved away from that implementation in the first place because it does not work correctly. The `WebView` can grow in length unexpectedly, and certain features (such as pinch to zoom) do not work along with the `NestedScrollView`. These issues are what the `NestedScrollWebView` solves, the only issue is that it does not work *perfectly* with the `SwipeRefreshLayout`.

Comment: That's make sense. Would be pretty helpful if you put this info into your question as well.

Comment: I used your code and tried to get your current behaviors with swiper, but it's seems work fine with me!

Comment: @Ibrahim Ah, I forgot, I did make one change to the `NestedScrollWebView`, I removed this line: `setOverScrollMode(WebView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER)`. I *want* over scroll indicators, but in other instances (even with over scroll indicators) the `SwipeRefreshLayout` intercepts the scroll gesture, so the over scroll indicator doesn't appear when scrolled past the top of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you will get some solution from new released interfaces:

`NestedScrollingChild` interfaces:

- [NestedScrollingChild](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/view/NestedScrollingChild)
- [NestedScrollingChild2](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/view/NestedScrollingChild2)
- [NestedScrollingChild3](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/view/NestedScrollingChild3)

`NestedScrollingParent` interfaces:

- [NestedScrollingParent](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/view/NestedScrollingParent)
- [NestedScrollingParent2](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/view/NestedScrollingParent2)
- [NestedScrollingParent3](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/view/NestedScrollingParent3)

Thank you.