# MAUI WebView inside a RefreshView tries to trigger "pull-to-refresh" when scrolling up is not finished

Tags: android, webview, maui

I have the following layout in my MainPage.Xaml

```
<RefreshView x:Name="refreshView"
                     IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}"
                     Refreshing="refreshView_Refreshing"
                     AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
     <WebView Source="https://csharpforums.net/forums/maui" />
<RefreshView>
```

And when I scroll down, stop, and then try to scroll up, it tries to refresh instead of scrolling up.
Here it says I need to put a scrollView inside the RefreshView for it to work ->  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/dotnet/maui-samples/userinterface-refreshview/
But the problem is, having a webview inside a scrollview has it's own bugs -> [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33688701/webview-height-grows-indefinitely-inside-a-nestedscrollview#:~:text=In%20one%20sentence%2C%20you%20just%20can%27t%20put%20your%20WebView%20inside%20NestedScrollView.%20This%20is%20working%20as%20intended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33688701/webview-height-grows-indefinitely-inside-a-nestedscrollview#:%7E:text=In%20one%20sentence%2C%20you%20just%20can%27t%20put%20your%20WebView%20inside%20NestedScrollView.%20This%20is%20working%20as%20intended).

How can I achieve pull-to-refresh for webview in MAUI?

Comment: I don’t think pull-to-refresh will work well with a web view.  I’d suggest using a different refresh mechanism

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

xaml:

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp2.NewPage1"
             Title="NewPage1">
    <RefreshView x:Name="refreshView"
                 Refreshing="refreshView_Refreshing">
        
        <ScrollView>
            <WebView x:Name="webview"
                     Source="https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/refreshview?view=net-maui-8.0"/>
        </ScrollView>
        
    </RefreshView>
</ContentPage>
```

xaml.cs:

```cs
public partial class NewPage1 : ContentPage
{
    public NewPage1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


   private void refreshView_Refreshing(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        refreshView.IsRefreshing = true;
        webview.Reload();
        refreshView.IsRefreshing = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't use this solution because if I place the webview inside a scrollView, it will grow infinitely. This is explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33688701/webview-height-grows-indefinitely-inside-a-nestedscrollview#:~:text=In%20one%20sentence%2C%20you%20just%20can%27t%20put%20your%20WebView%20inside%20NestedScrollView.%20This%20is%20working%20as%20intended.